# referencing CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to construct an HTML link element referencing a CSS file and I would like to use the same reference from multiple documents.

For example, my CSS file is in: {root}/style/style.css

For files in {root}, I use: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />`
But for files in {root}/inc, I have to use `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" />`

Is there a reference to {root} that I can use: something like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{root}/style/style.css" />
```

Sorry for noob question and thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start the URL with a slash, the {root} is implicit:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple / usually means "start from root"

Comment: to clarify, hrefs that start  with /, as in /foo/bar, are relative to the root of the domain; hrefs that don't (and don't include a domain) are relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" />
```

If you have a "/" at the beginning of a file reference, it means it is an absolute reference starting at the root. Without the "/" it would be a relative reference to {wherever-your-document-is}/style/style.css.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<base>` element: [Rec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE), but unfortunately, this will also have impact on any other, normal hyperlink in your page.

If you use XHTML (the real stuff, nothing for IE users), take a look at [xml:base](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/).

Cheers,